# How to use callback for multiple json array in retrofit?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am trying retrofit how to get data from below response

```
{
  "schedule_students": [
    {
      "id": "753",
      "sch_id": "153"
    },
    {
      "id": "765",
      "sch_id": "153"
    }
  ],
  "s_students": [
    {
      "id": "753",
      "s_id": "153"
    },
    {
      "id": "765",
      "s_id": "153"
    }
  ],
  "schedu": [
    {
      "id": "753",
      "ch_id": "153"
    },
    {
      "id": "765",
      "ch_id": "153"
    }
  ],
  "delids": "no",
  "expdelids": "no",
  "lastsyncdate": "2015-06-01 10:33:19"
}
```

In my API response It's having multiple JSON array. How to retrieve all data from this response

Comment: Post the URL for API here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create POJOs (**P**lain **O**ld **J**ava **O**bjects) for the JSON data sets.
Use this [tool](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to generate POJOs.

**SStudent.class**

```
package com.example.someapp;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

package com.example.someapp;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class SStudent {

    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("s_id")
    @Expose
    private String sId;

    /**
    * 
    * @return
    * The id
    */
    public String getId() {
    return id;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @param id
    * The id
    */
    public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @return
    * The sId
    */
    public String getSId() {
    return sId;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @param sId
    * The s_id
    */
    public void setSId(String sId) {
    this.sId = sId;
    } 
}
```

Similarly, Other generate for other classes.

And finally,

**SomeClass.java**

```
package com.example.someapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class SomeClass {

    @SerializedName("schedule_students")
    @Expose
    private List<ScheduleStudent> scheduleStudents = new ArrayList<ScheduleStudent>();
    @SerializedName("s_students")
    @Expose
    private List<SStudent> sStudents = new ArrayList<SStudent>();
    @Expose
    private List<Schedu> schedu = new ArrayList<Schedu>();
    @Expose
    private String delids;
    @Expose
    private String expdelids;
    @Expose
    private String lastsyncdate;

    /**
    * 
    * @return
    * The scheduleStudents
    */
    public List<ScheduleStudent> getScheduleStudents() {
    return scheduleStudents;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @param scheduleStudents
    * The schedule_students
    */
    public void setScheduleStudents(List<ScheduleStudent> scheduleStudents) {
    this.scheduleStudents = scheduleStudents;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @return
    * The sStudents
    */
    public List<SStudent> getSStudents() {
    return sStudents;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @param sStudents
    * The s_students
    */
    public void setSStudents(List<SStudent> sStudents) {
    this.sStudents = sStudents;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @return
    * The schedu
    */
    public List<Schedu> getSchedu() {
    return schedu;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @param schedu
    * The schedu
    */
    public void setSchedu(List<Schedu> schedu) {
    this.schedu = schedu;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @return
    * The delids
    */
    public String getDelids() {
    return delids;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @param delids
    * The delids
    */
    public void setDelids(String delids) {
    this.delids = delids;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @return
    * The expdelids
    */
    public String getExpdelids() {
    return expdelids;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @param expdelids
    * The expdelids
    */
    public void setExpdelids(String expdelids) {
    this.expdelids = expdelids;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @return
    * The lastsyncdate
    */
    public String getLastsyncdate() {
    return lastsyncdate;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @param lastsyncdate
    * The lastsyncdate
    */
    public void setLastsyncdate(String lastsyncdate) {
    this.lastsyncdate = lastsyncdate;
    }

}
```

Use the SomeClass.java in your Retrofit API interface like this.

```
 @GET("/your_api_endpoint")
 SomeClass getSomeClass(@Query("param") int param);
```

Then access it normally as an object of SomeClass after calling `getSomeClass(param)`.